# Centroid and center circumscribed spheres in simplex

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry

I'm looking for a proof for this problem on simplex which I think it is true

> **Question.** $A_0A_1...A_n$ is a simplex in the Euclidean space $\Bbb E^n$. $G$ is its centroid and its center circumscribed sphere is $O.$ Let $O_i$ be the centers circumscribed sphere of the simplex $GA_{0}A_{1}...A_{i-1}A_{i+1}...A_n$. Prove that $O$ is centroid of the simplex $O_0O_1...O_n.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $O$ be the origin, $\vec{OA_i}=a_i$, $\vec{OO_i}=p_i$, $\vec{OG}=a$.

Then $\|a_i\|=1$ and $\sum a_i/(n+1)=a$. We want to prove that $\sum p_i=0$.

We know that for $i \neq j$:
\begin{align}
\|p_i-a\|^2 &= \|p_i-a_j\|^2\\
(p_i,a_j) &= (p_i,a)+\frac{\|a_j\|^2-\|a\|^2}{2}.
\end{align}
Summing up over all $j\ne i$:
\begin{align}
(p_i,(n+1)a-a_i) &= n(p_i,a)+\frac{n-n\|a\|^2}{2} \\
(p_i,a_i)        &= (p_i,a)+\frac{-n+n\|a\|^2}{2} \\
\sum_i(p_i,a_j)   &= (p_j,a_j)+\sum_{k\ne i}(p_k,a_j)=\sum_i (p_i,a).
\end{align}
Now $\sum_i p_i$ is orthogonal to $a-a_i$, but these vectors generate the whole space and we conclude that $\sum_i p_i=0$.

Answer (score 4):

This is a special case of the "circumcenter of mass" theorem. See the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumcenter_of_mass) and

*Akopyan, Arseniy V.*, [**Some remarks on the circumcenter of mass**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00454-014-9596-3), Discrete Comput. Geom. 51, No. 4, 837-841 (2014). [ZBL1301.51022](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1301.51022).